# Pivot table not working properly

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query:

```
select * from dbPratiche
pivot
(
count(Compagnia)
for 
(convert(char(3),  [Data creazione pratica], 0))
in ([jan],[feb],[mar],[apr],[may],[jun],[jul],[aug],[sep],[October],[nov],[dec])
) pvt
```

I want to pivot my table on monthname from one [Data creazione pratica] column having date values in it.

But I'm getting an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

I checked all brackets, all brackets are correct.

Please tell me where I am making a mistake in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it through:

```
select * from (
select convert(char(3),  [Data creazione pratica], 0) as monthOF ,[Compagnia] 
  from dbPratiche where ISNULL([Data creazione pratica],'')!='')as temp
pivot
(
count(Compagnia)
for   monthOF in
 (jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,Oct,nov,dec)
) pvt
```